# Name a member function based on template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I’m looking for a solution to name a member function of an object based on a template parameter.

Example (FunctionName):

```
template <FunctionName, typename ...Args>
class FooTemplate
{
    virtual void FunctionName (Args...) = 0;
    void OtherInternalFunction (void)
    {
        FunctionName( …. );
    }
}
```

The FooTemplate class is a base class implemented in many classes. Some classes are derived from multiple classes and should implement different functions for each of them.

At this moment I have a solution by defining an “in-between” class, but it is way easier when the function could be named directly.

Current solution:

```
template <typename ...Args>
class FooTemplate
{
    virtual void execute (Args...) = 0;
    void OtherInternalFunction (void)
    {
        execute ( …. );
    }
}


Class InBetween : private FooTemplate<bool>
{
    virtual void  execute (bool foo) final
    {
        FunctionName(foo);
    }
    virtual void FunctionName (bool) = 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it really about "naming" or is it simply calling a different function selected by given template parameter? The first one is impossible.

Comment: @Klaus I’m afraid you are right, what I want is really about naming. But I hope someone knows a bit more as I do…

Comment: As said: No chance! But I believe you have no need for using "automated name creation". It is quite common to do different things on a specialized template or template parameter. So you should think again. I believe we are talking about a XY Problem.

Comment: Seems complicate to just have `class C { virtual ~C() = default; virtual void execute(bool) = 0;};`.

Comment: @Jarod42, the example with the bool is just an example, we use it with many different and multiple types. We need this complex way because we work on a linked list of function hooks/call-backs that should be runtime joinable and work in an (existing) embedded system without runtime allocations.

Comment: As `FooTemplate<int>` is different than `FooTemplate<bool>` I don't see how you can easily do ink list with those unrelated classes as the one I proposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like we have to stay by our workaround with the “in-between” class. This because of @Klaus and we both think it’s not possible. Is was more a question to see if we are missing something and there are options to do this in one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
template <class T>
class FooTemplate;

class FooTemplate<bool>;
```

Then defined these classes as you wish.